# Writing content, of a table in MS Word, using PowerShell. Order is incorrect

Tags: powershell

Below is the code:

```
$objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application

$filename = 'C:\Chicago_NewUser.doc'
$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($filename)

$LETable = $objDocument.Tables.Item(1)
$LETableCols = $LETable.Columns.Count
$LETableRows = $LETable.Rows.Count


Write-output "Starting to write... "

for($r=0; $r -le $LETableRows; $r++) {
    for($c=0; $c -le $LETableCols; $c++) {
        Write-host $r "x" $c
        $content = $LETable.Cell($r,$c).Range.Text
        Write-host $content
    }
}
$objDocument.Close()
$objWord.Quit()
```

The document is a 2003 Word document with a table - 2 cols and 3 rows. But the output as printed starts with the text in the 3rd row and 1st column.

The Word document is available here:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W0usG4ASsvd3PqQ20l7P8rq0hWBsYlrI0iM1S5ZcumU/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just start your indexs at 1 it will do the trick. I also add a line at the end to close winword correctly.

```
$objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application

$filename = 'c:\silogix\SILOGIX.doc'
$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($filename)

$LETable = $objDocument.Tables.Item(1)
$LETableCols = $LETable.Columns.Count
$LETableRows = $LETable.Rows.Count


Write-output "Starting to write... "

for($r=1; $r -le $LETableRows; $r++) {
    for($c=1; $c -le $LETableCols; $c++) {
        Write-host $r "x" $c
        $content = $LETable.Cell($r,$c).Range.Text
        Write-host $content
    }
}
$objDocument.Close()
$objWord.Quit()
# Stop Winword Process
$rc = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWord)
```